# Does sharedpreferences become null when application runs through out of memory issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using shared preferences through out my application, after using the application more that 3 hours or so, it behaves weird. Application does not crashes, but it does not work as expected. I checked the log and it says null shared preferences.

Does excess memory use by application, clears shared preferences ?

Comment: Sachchidanand did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepted answer is wrong i guess.

Not sure about behaviour when the amount of memory is not enough, you shall get OOM i think. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148282/read-speed-of-sharedpreferences/19148351#19148351), `SharedPreference` is stored in Memory once it is loaded and and i think it will get removed once that specific Context it belongs to is destroyed.

Also you can check [linked code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#L141) that `SharedPreference` is indeed stored in Context inside Map

Answer (score 1):

No. The shared preferences aren't stored in the memory, but on the internal storage of the device.

The shared preferences are emptied only, when you uninstall the application, or when you clear the application data.