# Read speed of SharedPreferences

Tags: android, performance, sharedpreferences

How fast are `SharedPreferences`?  Is there a way to put them in memory for reading?  I have a small amount of data that a `ListView` has to query to display each cell, and I'm worried that a call to flash memory will be too slow.  I'm not worried about write speed, as writes will happen infrequently.  I'm considering just using a JSON object to persist the data instead of `SharedPreferences`. Any thoughts?

Comment: SharedPreferences is essentially a xml-file residing in the app "sandbox" storage. It can be accessed and viewed through ADB.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> Is there a way to put them in memory for reading?

They are in memory, after the first reference. The first time you retrieve a specific `SharedPreferences` (e.g., `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`), the data is loaded from disk, and kept around.

Comment: you say, the whole saved data in `SharedPreferences` will be loaded once you get instance of `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` ???

Comment: @MoshErsan: Yes. The `SharedPreferences` is held in a static `HashMap` of `SharedPreferences` in `ContextImpl`. It will remain there until the process is terminated. See `sSharedPrefs` in https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java

Comment: what is the benefit of doing it like this?!!

Comment: @MoshErsan: Among other things, it ensures that all components of your app, asking for the same `SharedPreferences`, get the actual same `SharedPreferences` instance, and so they cannot get out of sync with each other.

Comment: I was reading `SharedPreferencesImpl`->`startLoadFromDisk`, in this case if we saved a big data in it, it may cause `OOE`.

Comment: @MoshErsan: Correct. `SharedPreferences` should be small.

Comment: @MohammadErsan for some data it's better to use database (SQLite) and SharedPreferences for some settings. I don't think your apps have a lot of settings

Comment: bad answer, you still have to load from disk, even you have the reference. Gosh!

Comment: @Devon: "you still have to load from disk" -- not according to [the source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java;l=181-186?q=ContextImpl&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) and [the source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java;l=74-75). Preferences and their values are cached.

Answer (score 19):

My advice is to test your performance first, and then start worrying about speed. In general, you'll be happier with an app that prioritizes maintainability as well as speed. When engineers start out to achieve performance before they get the app stable, the result is an app that runs a bit faster but has lots of bugs.

Answer (score 17):

According to [this](https://yakivmospan.com/blog/best-practice-shared-preferences/) link, `getSharedPreferences` is not that much heavy because it opens file only when you call `getSharedPreferences` first time:

```
// There are 1000 String values in preferences

SharedPreferences first = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// call time = 4 milliseconds

SharedPreferences second = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// call time = 0 milliseconds

SharedPreferences third = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// call time = 0 milliseconds
```

But using `get` methods will take some time for the first time you call it:

```
first.getString("key", null)
// call time = 147 milliseconds

first.getString("key", null)
// call time = 0 milliseconds

second.getString("key", null)
// call time = 0 milliseconds

third.getString("key", null)
// call time = 0 milliseconds
```

Comment: So it looks like a "lazy“ implementation the loading happens on first get.

Comment: amazing article! thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Another benchmark for those interested in larger files.  The snippet below run on a 2013(?) Samsung SMT-350 tablet (1.2 GHz Quad-Core, Qualcomm) revealed:

- About 80 seconds to create 10000 7k strings
- About 3.5 seconds to 'open' (getSharedPreferences) the 70mb file
- About 1/10ms to read any 7k string once the SP was open

Note: the file creation crashed at 5500, but continued without problem.  I am NOT recommending the use of 70MB SPs, this was for an unlikely edge case test, and 100x over-test.

```
        G.logTime("MAKE HUGE FILE", true);
        String sevenKString = App.getAsset(this, "sample_map.txt");
        SharedPreferences.Editor spf = getSharedPreferences("TEST", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        G.logTime("SP OPEN", false);
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            spf.putString(i.toString(), sevenKString);
            spf.apply();
            G.logTime("SP ADD " + i.toString() + " (" + (7 * i) + ")", false);
        }

        G.logTime("SP OPEN", true);
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("TEST", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for (Integer i = 1; i < 10000; i += 10) {
            file = sp.getString(i.toString(), null);
            G.logTime("SP READ = " + i.toString(), false);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

> I have a small amount of data that a ListView has to query to
>   display each cell

Can't you make a Singleton, a common class and read it from there from second time? I would do that.

Comment: There is no need to increase shared global state via Singletons. Android already has solutions for global state management via `SharedPreferences` and `Bundles`. It is enough. You should eliminate global state as much as you can