# Should SharedPreferences be a singleton? Conflicting answers

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Should SharedPreferences be a singleton class? I'm getting conflicting answers from sources. This blogpost tells me I should make a SharedPreferencesManager class as a singleton

https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-sharedpreferences-singleton-example/

```
public class SharePref {
    private static SharePref sharePref = new SharePref();
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private static final String PLACE_OBJ = "place_obj";

    private SharePref() {} //prevent creating multiple instances by making the constructor private

    //The context passed into the getInstance should be application level context.
    public static SharePref getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) {
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        }
        return sharePref;
    }

    public void savePlaceObj(String placeObjStr) {
        editor.putString(PLACE_OBJ, placeObjStr);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getPlaceObj() {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(PLACE_OBJ, "");
    }


    .  .  .
```

And this SO answer says I don't need to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148391/11110509

> There is no need to increase shared global state via Singletons. Android already has solutions for global state management via SharedPreferences and Bundles. It is enough. You should eliminate global state as much as you can

Which is it?

Comment: It's really up to the user of the API. There is no right or wrong regarding your question. You will only find opinionated answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imho singleton for `SharedPrefs` is redundant, you have to pass proper `Context` everytime when want to access, so this class may by also collection of static methods like this (kind of pseudo code):

```
public static void savePlaceObj(Context ctx, String placeObjStr) {
    Editor editor = getEditor(ctx);
    editor.putString(PLACE_OBJ, placeObjStr);
    editor.commit();
}

public static final String getPlaceObj(Context ctx) {
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PLACE_OBJ, "");
}

private static final SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
    return ctx.getSharedPreferences(ctx.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private static SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor(Context ctx) {
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).Editor();
}
```

in fact, when you use singleton for SPs then there will be temptation to use `getInstance(null)` at some point, beacuse "it was already initiated earlier for shure" - you can't be shure even when you place initiation in extended `Application` class. at least use annotation `getInstance(@NonNull Context context)`